# Partitioning a planar graph into spanning trees?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

Suppose I have a simple, planar graph, which I want to partition into three edge sets such that each set forms a spanning tree. I've made an attempt at a solution, but it requires a few assumptions that I'm not sure I can make; here's what I've got so far:

Let's say we have a tree with *n* nodes; then that tree must have *n-1* edges. [[ASSUMPTION: All possible spanning trees of a graph must have an equal number of nodes, and, those spanning trees must not be disjointed.]] Thus, given that the graph is both simple and planar, and assuming that we *can* partition the graph into three edge sets such that each set forms a spanning tree, then we can say that the graph has at most *3n-6* edges. Then if we create three equal partitions, each edge set can have at most *n-2* edges, and there is no way to partition the graph so that ALL three sets have greater than *n-2* edges, which is what we need to make every set a spanning tree of the graph (given that they must have *n-1* edges).

I'm not quite sure though how I can make the leaps that:
1) All spanning trees in the graph must have a an equal number of nodes (though intuitively, this makes sense to me).
2) If a graph has multiple spanning sets within it, those sets are necessarily not disjointed. (I'm less intuitively sure of this one, and that's probably not a good way to approach the problem, but it seems possible, only I'm not sure how to prove it, but it's all I've got so far.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "All spanning trees in the graph must have an equal number of nodes" -- consider what it *means* to be a spanning subgraph.

I can't tell what you mean by "If a graph has multiple spanning sets within it, those sets are necessarily not disjointed."

Comment: For the second part, I mean that every spanning tree in the graph must intersect - at the nodes - with every other spanning tree in the graph - but I suppose this follows from what you already mentioned? That is, what it _means_ to be a spanning tree, which, in particular, means that all the nodes of the graph are contained within the spanning tree, only that the edges are different. But I think I just answered my own question, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I think you pretty much have.